# Problem while scanning two vectors back by back using pushback

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ programming and stackoverflow as well. My problem is:

```
int x,y;
vector<int> v1,v2;
cout<<"Enter the elements in vector"<<endl;
while(cin>>x) 
    v1.push_back(x);
while(cin>>y)
    v2.push_back(y);
for(auto i:v1)
    cout<<i<<endl;
for(auto j:v2)
    cout<<j<<endl;
```

This piece of code I am using in a program and I have included required libraries.

PROBLEM--
The first while is working fine and pushing in vector .But the second while is not working and is skipping the scanning of second vector.
I don't know why this is happening so I found on net that we have to clear buffer therefore I used cin.ignore() after the first while but still skipping the second vector input and pushback.
It is compiling fine but not working as expected??

Comment: This code is definitely not the code you compiled. `pushback` is not a member of `std::vector`, that would be `push_back`. Please post a proper [mre].

Comment: `while(cin>>x)` means "read as many integers as possible". How is the program supposed to know when to stop reading? Your design is flawed. If you show us some input and how you expect it to be read we maybe can find a working solution or a duplicate.

Comment: while(cin>>x) will read as much numbers I would like to enter . To stop it 1)Entering an invalid input stops.2)Entering ctrl+Z which is end of line character also stops it. Sample input - 10 20 30 45 abcd. So cin will read integers and then push onto vector but when it encounters abcd (some invalid input) cin evaluates to false (cin only evaluates to true if the input is valid) and therefore first loop stops . My first loop is working fine , reading the input then pushing and then stoping when I want but the second loop is not working. Program skips the second while and second vector is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first loop will read **all** the input and leave no input left to be added to the second vector. Ask yourself, how did you expect the first loop to know when to stop and move onto the second loop? I expect you have some wrong idea like that if you put the input for the second vector onto a new line the first loop will somehow know to stop. But `>>` doesn't work like that.

Plus you really meant `push_back` not `pushback`. Always post real code to SO. It's amazing how many mistakes are made when 'translating' code for posting to SO. Not surprisingly then posters get answers for the mistakes made when transcribing their code, not for the questions they really wanted to ask.

Comment: Actually , I am learning C++ from a book "C++ primer" . In this it is mentioned that if you want to scan something till user want , use while (cin>>v1) like this and to stop this scanning , 1).We can either enter something invalid so that cin in while evaluates to false and loop stops .2) We can enter Ctrl+Z which is end of line character to stop the loop. Therefore in the given code I am trying to scan till I want .The first loop is working fine and stops when I enter something invalid ( like abcd) but 2nd is not .Thanks for advice I will definitely put the actual code from next time onwards.

Comment: @DivyamBhutani OK, that's fine, but should have been mentioned before. C++ primer is a good book, so it should also mention that when you deliberately error the stream, you then need to use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(...);` (in that order) to get it working again. Perhaps you can look those two methods up.

Comment: Thanks @john . Its working after using cin.clear() and cin.ignore(....) . After reading your reply I checked the book and found these methods were mentioned in later section . Thanks again.